# Transfer data from Excel to Word via Excel VBA code without using clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, paste

I have a routine that extracts data from Excel and transfers it to a Word document, at the current cursor position. It works, step by step. However, depending on the volume of data copied or subsequent processing in loops, sometimes it displays an error, because when reaching the paste command, the clipboard is empty, because it was not copied completely and the Paste has no content to transfer to the Word document.

I found ways to slow down the processing or check the status of the Excel clipboard before Paste and get around this error but I don't want to go down that path.

My intention in this question is to define the destination of the data and the origin of the data without going through a Copy/Paste process, but defining this in another way, which does not use Excel's clipboard at any time.

I've done it within VBA Excel routines but I don't know how when it comes to a final destination in Word.

Would anyone be so kind as to instruct me on how to generate such code, without suggesting any other processing delay mechanisms? The volume of information to be copied is large and I need agility in the process not more delays.

```vb
Sub Export_Excel_to_Word()

Dim Word As Word.Application
Dim Doc As Word.Document
Dim wb As Workbook 
Dim IdxSheet As Worksheet 
Dim Interval As Range 'Temporary buffer to copy/paste

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Open Word

Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Word.Visible = True
Set Doc = Word.Documents.Open("E:\00 MyDocs W10\Existent_Doc_Word.docx")

'Copying data from Excel

Set IdxSheet = wb.Sheets("Index")
IdxSheet.Activate
'IdxSheet.Select 

'Copying the Specific Range
Set Interval = Range("First_Table") 'Pre-defined and named
Interval.Copy

With Doc
    .Application.Selection.Paste 
    'blank line
    .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
End With

.
.
.

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try `doc.PasteExcelTable` - it might be faster ... If you want to keep formatting, there won't be a way without clipboard

Comment: I think you should change `Range("First_Table")` and use something like `Range("A1:B23")` using variables to set the correct range for each sheet